# Where should I check state / throw exception?

Tags: python, exception

My situation is something like this:

```
class AbstractClass:
    def __init__(self, property_a):
        self.property_a = property_a

    @property
    def some_value(self):
        """Code here uses property_a but not property_b to determine some_value"""

    @property
    def property_a(self):
        return self.property_a

    @property
    def property_b(self):
        """Has to be implemented in subclass."""
        raise NotImplementedError


class Concrete1(AbstractClass):
    """Code here including an implementation of property_b"""


class Concrete2(AbstractClass):
    """Code here including an implementation of property_b"""
```

There is also a condition that if `property_b` is less than `property_a`, then `property_a` is invalid and thus the result of `some_value` is also invalid.

What I mean is this... if at any time during the object's lifetime, calling `property_b` would yield a number lower than calling `property_a`, there's a problem. However, property_b is **not a field**. It is determined dynamically based on *n* fields, where *n* >= 1. It is impossible to check this condition while setting `property_b` because `property_b` itself is never set. Really, setters are not anticipated to be used *anywhere* here. All fields are likely to be set in the constructors and then left alone. This means that `property_a` will be known in the constructor for `AbstractClass` and `property_b` only *after* evaluating the constructor for the concrete classes.

**<update>**
The fundamental problem is this: I need to check `property_a` for validity, but when `property_a` is set (the most intuitive place to check it), `property_b` is undefined.
**</update>**

I want to ensure that `property_b` is never less than `property_a`. How should I handle it?

Check `property_a` against `property_b` in...

1. `AbstractClass.__init__`. This is actually impossible because `property_b` hasn't been defined yet.
2. `AbstractClass.property_a`. This seems problematic because I would be throwing an exception in a getter.
3. Each concrete implementation of `property_b`. Not only would I be throwing an exception in a getter, I would be duplicating code. Also `property_b` does not logically depend on `property_a`.
4. `AbstractClass.some_value`. This is still throwing an exception in a getter. Also, it is logically impossible for `property_b` to be less than `property_a` *all the time*, not just when trying to determine `some_value`. Further, if subclasses decide to add other properties that depend on `property_a`, they may forget to check it against `property_b`.
5. Concrete setters for `property_b`. These don't exist. `property_b` is sometimes determined from a value set in the constructor, sometimes calculated from multiple values. Also, code duplication.
6. Concrete class `__init__` methods. Code duplication. Someone may forget.
7. ???

**UPDATE**

I think what is causing confusion is that `property_b` is not simply a field. `property_b` relies on calculations. It is really more a function than a property, if it helps to think about it that way.

Comment: Bear in mind that I'm saying this as someone who has done this myself:  have you considered that you're overcomplicating things somewhere?  I don't really understand your question, but surely it can't be *this* complicated to define three properties.  Are you sure there's not a 90% solution you could implement.

Comment: Well, I could pull property b and some value into the subclasses, but then I would have code duplication, and the whole goal of my architecture is to have superclasses do as much work as they can so subclasses are as small as possible. I have 12 classes in this module at 4 levels but only 140 lines of actual code. The architecture is almost trivial to explain, reflects the problem domain and ends up with "leaf" classes that are so small you can typically fit them on one screen even with their (copious) documentation.

Comment: I think the 90% solution is going to be take Alex Martelli's advice, but to simplify things make it so the subclasses never change anything that affects property b. Then I can just call the validator at the end of each constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a method `_validate_b(self, b)` (single leading underscore to indicate "protected", i.e., callable from derived classes but not by general client code) that validates the value of b (which only subclasses know) vs the value of a (which the abstract superclass does know).

Make subclasses responsible for calling the validation method whenever they're doing something that could change their internal value for b. In your very general case, the superclass cannot identify when b's value changes; since the responsibility of that change lies entirely with the subclasses, then the responsibility for triggering validation must also be with them (the superclass can *perform* validation, given the proposed new value of b, but it cannot know *when* validity must be checked).  So, document that clearly.

If most subclasses fall into broad categories in terms of the strategies they use to affect their b's values, you can factor that out into either intermediate abstract classes (inheriting from the general one and specializing the general approach to "determining b", including the validation call), or (better, if feasible) some form of Strategy design pattern (typically implemented via either composition, or mix-in inheritance). But this has more to do with convenience (for concrete-subclass authors) than with "guaranteeing correctness", since a given concrete subclass *might* bypass such mechanisms.

If you need to, you can offer a "debug/test mode" where properties are validated redundantly on access (probably not advisable in production use, but for debugging and testing it would help catch errant subclasses that are not properly calling validation methods).

Comment: @Daniel, you're welcome!  I wish there was a way to automate this better, but I do think this more explicit approach is going to be sounder for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The golden rule is to "encapsulate" `property_b` so that the subclass provides part of the implementation, but not all of it.

```
class AbstractClass:
    def __init__(self, property_a):
        self._value_of_a = property_a

    @property
    def get_b( self ):
       self.validate_a()
       self._value_of_b = self.compute_b()
       self.validate_other_things()
       return self._value_of_b

   def compute_b( self ):
       raise NotImplementedError
```

It's hard to say precisely what's supposed to happen when you have two classes and you're *asking* about allocation of responsibility.

It appears that you want the superclass to be responsible for some aspect of the relationship between a and b

It appears that you want the the subclass to be responsible for some other aspect of computing b, and not responsible for the relationship.

If this is what you want, then your design must assign responsibility by decomposing things into the part the superclass is responsible for and the part the subclass is responsible for.

Comment: This gives me some other stuff to think about. Thanks for sticking with it despite my unclear explanation.

Comment: The unclear explanation (sometimes) a symptom of something simple being buried under confusion or useless complexity.  90% of the time, complexity is the result of failing to assign responsibility correctly.  This is often because responsibilities or actors aren't specified simply and clearly.  As you simplify and clarify your explanation, you strip away useless complexity.  Keep simplifying.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you don't raise `raise NotImplementedError` but call a method instead which raises this error. Subclasses then have to override that method (instead of `property_b`). In `property_b`, you call the method and then verify the result.

Rationale: You should check the value as soon as possible (which is when someone changes it). Otherwise, an illegal value could be set and cause a problem much later in the code when no one can say how it got there.

Alternatively, you could store the value and a stack trace. When the value is used, you can then check the value and print the original stack trace as "value was changed here".

Comment: I think perhaps I was somewhat unclear. This goes to case 3. Property b is not the one that really needs checked. The validity of property b does not depend on property a at all.

Comment: Also, when property a is set, there is no way to check it. Property b has to be defined before property a can be checked.

Comment: You must do the check as soon as you have both properties. Create a validate method and call it from both setters as soon as both properties are valid. Do this in the base class and have the derived classes implement helper methods in order to avoid duplicate code.